# simple XOR algorithm

Tags: c, string, cryptography, xor

Although I've used C++ a lot, I'm struggling with the C differences (mainly in strings).

Could you please show me a simple single function that encrypts a message with a key using XOR comparison.

Thank-you

EDIT:
Both the key and the message are char*

Comment: I would add what I've tryed but I'm on my mobile

Comment: Note that an XOR function shouldn't really be considered encrypting, it's way too easy to crack.

Comment: @Mark, sorry for the lack of clarity but this is my introduction, so to speak, before I try other algorithms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I hacked around for a minute and came up with this (only vaguely tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * xorencrypt(char * message, char * key) {
    size_t messagelen = strlen(message);
    size_t keylen = strlen(key);

    char * encrypted = malloc(messagelen+1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < messagelen; i++) {
        encrypted[i] = message[i] ^ key[i % keylen];
    }
    encrypted[messagelen] = '\0';

    return encrypted;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char * message = "test message";
    char * key = "abc";

    char * encrypted = xorencrypt(message, key);
    printf("%s\n", encrypted);
    free(encrypted);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the function `xorencrypt` allocates and returns a new string, so it's the caller's responsibility to free it when done.

Comment: Good solution for the key length; I didn't think about %.

Comment: The returned string is not NULL terminated here.

Comment: This really won't work reliably. The problem is that the encrypted string may contain any character at any point in the string, including '\0'. Thus you have no way of knowing where the end of the encrypted string is.

Comment: @GregS: true, and I considered that, but the OP hasn't specified that he needs that information (and it's trivially obtainable from `strlen(message)` anyway).

Comment: @GregS: Sure there is, as a guard in the case where (a) the XOR'd string *doesn't* contain a `\0` and (b) the programmer is lazy and tries to depend on its null-termination without finding the length by hand. Rare and undesirable situation? Probably. Defensive programming? Yes.

Answer (score 4):

C is very close to Assembler, so this example is short:

```
while (*string)
    *string++ ^= key;
```

assuming `char *string;` and `char key`.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this is exactly how you would write it in C++ also.

Comment: @Mike I know, but manipulating cstrings are somewhat new to me; do you need to initialize strings to '\0' after malloc?

Comment: If you're not sure of the length, yes; you'll note my solution above takes care of that issue instead by only allocating a string of the same length as the original message (so you're sure the entire string will be filled with data, and doesn't need `\0`-filling).

Comment: @Will03uk You don't have to initialize the string data if you plan to write it, however should make sure it is NULL-terminated.

Comment: @Will03uk You need to initialize memory before you can *read* it, but you can write to it without a problem. And you never have to fill a block of memory with zeros when working with strings, since string functions only read up to the first `\0`. However, you will see that zero-filling be done occasionally because people (ab)use strncat for security reasons. Really the only time you need to do that is when working with fixed-width fields, which are used in systems programming.

Comment: Again, sorry for lack of clarity; by initializing, I meant NULL-terminating the first byte before the use of a function such as strcat. Thank-you for the help

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, combine the answers from @ott-- & @Tim to form Xortron.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *xor(char *string, const char *key)
{
    char *s = string;
    size_t length = strlen(key), i = 0;
    while (*s) {
            *s++ ^= key[i++ % length];
    }
    return string;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *key = "abc";
    if (argc < 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: no input\n", argv[0]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s\n", xor(xor(argv[1], key), key));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```